# User profile page links to broken search results

Tags: bug, tags, profile-page, search

I was looking over [my user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625403/amalloy), and I noticed I have 18 answers in the [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) tag. I suspected some of those should probably actually be tagged [map-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map-function) instead, so I clicked on the link (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:625403+[map]) to look through those answers and re-tag as necessary.

However, as you can see, that link goes to a search-results page with no results. I noticed that [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) is actually a synonym for [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) now, and I apparently have no answers tagged [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary). So it seems like the problem is that I have answers in a tag that no longer exists, which makes it impossible to search for.

The behavior I would expect is that the link in my profile should go to some page with 18 results, whether those are tagged [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map), [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary), or some mix of both. Saying I have 18 answers in a tag but linking to a page that says I have zero seems incorrect to me.